# convergence test for $\sum\frac{\sin(5^n)}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What test to be used for detecting convergence of the series of $n$th term $$\dfrac{\sin(5^n)}{n!}$$ ?

I think that comparison test should work here, but I can't find the correct series to compare it with.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|\frac{\sin(5^n)}{n!}\right|\leqslant \left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|=\frac{1}{n!}\leqslant \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Comment: How to write big brackets of absolute value?

Comment: \left| ... \right|

Comment: In the context menu of the formula you can find "Show Math As > TeX Commands" which shows all the trick and secrets behind a formula. (Or use the "edit" link to inspect the source code.)